# RPG.SE Ambassador Program

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Based on the initial response to my previous post (*[CHAOS is here! How can we help?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/chaos-is-here-how-can-we-help)*) I think that starting an **RPG.SE Ambassador Program** is a great place to start. Eventually I want to expand the program to include Meetup groups and local stores, but right now I want to start with you, the actual RPG.SE users. *You*...are our ambassadors.

If you would like Stack Exchange to provide your RPG session/night/event/hoopla with Stack Exchange cups and pizza, please contact me at ***brett* at *stack exchange* dot *com*** with the following information:

- A brief description of your gathering/event/soiree and what RPG you will be playing
- When the event takes place
- The number of people expected to attend your event (**minimum of 5** required for involvement in the ambassador program)
- The address where cups and food should be sent

Hopefully this will be a fun way for all of you to share the awesomeness of Stack Exchange with your friends, as we slowly try to take over the world. Once we get a site design and some swag created, those items can be sent along with food and we can start spreading our influence to Meetup groups and RPG stores. **Regarding having an event in your local RPG store**, please clear it with the store first. But please, evangelize RPG.SE to your stores by having approved events in them. When swag gets made, I want to send it to your stores. This is a good way to start a relationship.

**P.S.** I apologize if any of my terminology is annoyingly n00b. Seeing people write "spiderman" instead of "Spider-Man" is a pet peeve of mine, and I'd hate to think I have done the RPG equivalent. Show me my errors!

Comment: No faux pas done so far and your terminology is fine.  Thank you for your efforts and work.

Comment: Should this get featured (or whatever it is) that gets it visible on the main site so more than the dozen of us who poke our heads into meta see it?

Comment: Man, I wish this had been around a few years ago, I knew all the people who organized the local cons (3-4 a year, 30-40 people each, sometimes more.) Would have been the perfect place for this kinda thing. If anyone runs LFR cons I think you should have a look at that.

Comment: @SimonWithers It should be, yeah. We can get an ad to run on the main RPG site, I do believe, but that might be hard to do without an official RPG.SE design. I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 8):

Do you send things outside of the US?

Answer (score 6):

Just a note for those playing at a FLGS (Friendly Local Game Store), you probably want to clear this with the owner...

Answer (score 4):

Brett, how big of a group are you looking for?  My local game has six or seven players (plus other people hanging out in the shop), but many can be as small as only three or four people.

**How big should an event be before we apply?**

Comment: @Brett And are groups hosted in a home ok or is this for public convention only stuff?

Comment: @BrettWhite we're not really taking advantage of this because we have a lot of questions... How big?  Are you ready to get this on a grand scale, like if I tell some organized play groups like Pathfinder Society it's open to them?  Hello?

Answer (score 2):

What about non RPG events? I'm giving a presentation at the Richmond Java Users Group in March. My presentations open with a bio where I basically state: I'm a role player too. I'm on a crusade to banish gamer shame (in the home town of Patrica Pulling no less; here's my last presentation , http://www.slideshare.net/timstone/html-xhtml-html5... "not exactly" was accompanied by a note that I prefer WRFP2e!).

I would expect about 30 people at this event, most geeks. Some players.

**Update**

First, a shout out to CHAOS and Brett White for supporting my presentation at RJUG! Thank you.

Second, thank you all for supporting my idea with the votes!

Below are pictures, screencaps, and slides from my presentation and a hat tip to @mxyzplk.

[image: Slide from RJUG presentation with shout out to CHAOS and RPG.SE]

[image: 'mxyzplk' as protrayed in various media]

[image: Choosing a tee...]

[image: So much good stuff!]

[image: Still playing D&D (in some form...)]

[image: My bio to the RJUG... RPG advocate? check!]

Comment: That seems like a bit of a stretch to me. I run a lot of user groups in Austin and wouldn't want to give out swag in the hopes that 1/10 of the audience are gamers.

Comment: @mxyzplk <counter-point>It's an **ambassador** program. The swag would be generic "stackexchange," but the presentation a shout out to RPG.SE. One is not _evangelizing_ at FLGSs or gaming groups, but "preaching to a choir" already ranting on rpg.net. My argument is about being an ambassador for RPG.SE outside of the normal contexts. And I would further argue, as one that "[runs] a lot of user groups in Austin," take ambassadorship out of your comfort zone. I was going to make a classic SNL point-counterpoint reference, but it might have been taken out of context.</counter-point>

Comment: Yeah, and we could just go hand the swag out at the local Starbuck's too.  Real people qualify leads...

Comment: As a co-manager of a user group in Indianapolis, I see enough problems with swag-for-users when the swag is directly related to the group's purpose and we've already qualified the recipients; I think the best use of a program like this is for people whom we already know to be RPGers.

Comment: Thanks to all that took this suggestion out of negative terrority!